# Unexpected behaviour of inactive tabs in Chrome 28 (beta)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have some software that uses a Chrome Extension to automate the browser (to crawl client web sites).

Usually we run several instances of this software in multiple tabs (up to 5) to parallel up work.

In Chrome 28 (beta) we have noticed that the inactive (background) tabs seems to be heavily throttled or running at a significantly lower priority. Benchmarks show that our extension is now running around 10 times slower in an inactive tab   than when in the active tab. A similar behaviour is also seen in the active tab if Chrome is minimised.

This behaviour is not seen in Chrome 27 (stable) where the performance in active/inactive tabs is comparable.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Our Chrome beta is (Version 28.0.1500.29 beta-m) running on Microsoft Windows 7 and Server 2008.

thanks
richard

Comment: Are you using Web Workers? `setInterval`? Or just chaining Ajax calls and success callbacks?

Comment: Hi @apsillers - Yes, we are using setTimeout in places which is currently set to 100ms. Web Workers are also used but not in the test case.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome throttle `setTimeout` and `setInterval` calls to no more than once per second when run inside of an inactive or minimized tab. Could that be your problem?

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Javascript performance when running in an unfocused tab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6585112/710446) -- the only thing that's not the same is that you seem to have *not* experienced this in Chrome 27, which is unusual. Perhaps Chrome only just deployed throttling to extension scripts?

Comment: Hi @apsillers - ok - just did a test and commented out the 100ms setTimeout code and the extension performance improved greatly. I think you right that a new 1 sec minimum has now been imposed for extensions in Chrome 28. Hopefully someone from the Chromium team will confirm this. Interestingly the performance is still not as good as Chrome 27 - I wonder if page loads are also now delayed ?

Answer (score 0):

On newest Chrome 55, this 'problem' (or maybe call it 'feature'?) still persists.

I've reproduced this problem on my build-page (runs lots of tests of an Ember application via QUnit) and on the background they take much longer. As @apsillers reported on a comment, this has been reported on another thread [Javascript performance when running in an unfocused tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6585112/710446)