# Angular $interval not working when in another tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem that, when I open my page and then open new tab, and go to that other tab my $intevral stops working.

In more details: I have countdown with progress bar and when I start it and while I'm in that tab everything works fine, but when I go to another tab it stops counting down, and when I come back it quickly counts down to proper value. For example if I leave it at 5 seconds left, and go to another tab and come back for example after 15 seconds I can see it is still at 5, but goes back to zero in less than second.

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
function startPause() {
    $scope.pause *= 10;
    pauseCountDown = $interval(function () {

        $scope.pause -= 1;
    }, 100);
}

 function stopPause() {
    $interval.cancel(pauseCountDown);
    pauseCountDown = undefined;

}

$scope.$watch('pause', function(newVal, oldval) {
    if (newVal != oldval) {

        $scope.pauseView = Math.round(newVal / 10);

        if (!$scope.isLongPause) {
            $scope.pausePercentage = newVal / $scope.routine.ShortPauseLengthInSeconds * 10;

        } else {

            $scope.logPausePercentage = newVal / $scope.routine.LongPauseLengthInSeconds * 10;

        }
        if (newVal < 1) {
            $scope.isLongPause = false;
            stopPause();
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div id="PauseProgress" data-ng-hide="isLongPause" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" data-ng-style="{width : (pausePercentage + '%')}">
    </div>
    <div id="PauseProgressLong" data-ng-show="isLongPause" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" data-ng-style="{width : (logPausePercentage + '%')}">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="PauseTimer" class="pause-timer">
    {{pauseView}}
</div>
```

And I have somewhat similar code with stopwatch, and with it everything works fine when I leave tab and go to another (maybe, biggest difference between them is that with stopwatch I'm not using $scope.$watch, could that be cause of problem?)

So my question is, why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Where's the fiddle or plunkr ? :)

Comment: Check the accepted answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585112/javascript-performance-when-running-in-an-unfocused-tab Maybe the problem you have is that you want the interval to trigger too often. Try changing the interval to 1000 and bigger and see if it helps.

Comment: @RaYell Yes that was the problem, thanks !

Comment: @ExpertSystem if you are still interested in plunkr, here is link (note for some reason progress bar doesn't start as full,but unfortunately I don't have time to fix it, but you'll get idea how whole thing works) http://plnkr.co/edit/SSwNwvEyQ4SRQfOhLU4B