# Chrome makes my extension run slow when the tab is in background

Tags: google-chrome, loops, google-chrome-extension, reload

I wrote a Chrome extension: If a page's URL includes a specific hashtag, the extension performs a action, then reloads the page, finds the hashtag, performs an action, reloads ... and so on. Infinite loop.

**Now my question:**
I added a console.log which displays the time that it takes from reloading until the page is completely there and ready. This includes some internal loading on this website (waiting for a div to display a text).

- With the tab being **"active"** or "focused", it constantly takes **160 to
  250 milliseconds**
- With the tab being **"inactive"** or "another tab in focus", the loading
  time instantly goes up to around **2500 milliseconds / 2 seconds**

As soon as i click the tab again. The loading time goes back to the "normal" 160 to 250 milliseconds.

Is this some kind of "feature" in Chrome? Is there any way to disable it and force chrome to fast-load a background-tab?

By the way: I found out that setTimeouts are limited to a minimum of 1000ms when the tab is running in the background. Is there anyway to work around this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am kind of new to chrome extensions!

Greetings, Mr. Inka!

Comment: You're going to have to show your code if you want it to be fixed.

Comment: Feature, Chrome give high priority CPU time to active tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature/bug of Chrome. I've got some testing running inside Chrome and when the browser window is on the front, the testing goes much more faster. Similar problem reported on stackoverflow [Javascript performance when running in an unfocused tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585112/javascript-performance-when-running-in-an-unfocused-tab)

It's a feature if you consider it's optimizing the user experience, it's a bug if you consider you are a developer making an extension that needs to have everything ok.

Comment: You js developers have to stop hogging the CPU…

Comment: You are right (and funny) @LtWorf ! Happy StackOverflowing stuff!